# Download historical financial data

Tags: data-request, finance

Do you know some website where a student could download historical financial data?

The best one I have found  is this:  http://www.tr4der.com/

Since I need older prices (from 80-90'), and since I need them for academic purposes (maybe there are free databases if you're a student), my question is different from any other which have been posted.

Comment: What kind of *financial data*? The whole world runs on money, so you need to be more precise. You are also collapsing *academic purposes* with *free*, they do not automatically imply each other. Please [edit] your question and **be specific**.